# dragula JS move from one list to another with on click event

Tags: javascript, html, draggable, dragula

Im using Dragula JS for the drag and drop functionality and I would like to also have the option to move back and forth the elements in my list with the mouse click without loosing the drag and drop functionality.. How can I achieve this?

so I click on element 1 and it moves to the list. 
I click it back from that list and it moves back. 
That's the idea.

I prepared a fiddle with the basic drag and drop if it helps.
http://jsfiddle.net/vf6dnwxj/10/

my structure in the fiddle above:

```
<div class="wrapper panel panel-body">
<ul id="left1" class="cont-dragula">

</ul>
<ul id="right1" class="cont-dragula">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3.</li>
    <li>Item 4.</li>
    <li>Item 5.</li>
    <li>Item 6.</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
dragula([left1, right1]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well dragula doesn't do anything special it just moves items around. So You can simply move them around Yourself:

```
var leftList = document.querySelector('#left1');
var rightList = document.querySelector('#right1');
var list = document.querySelectorAll('#right1 li, #left1 li');
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  list[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        if (this.parentNode.id == 'right1') {
        leftList.appendChild(this);
      } else {
        rightList.appendChild(this);
      }
  });
}
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vf6dnwxj/11/)

If You want dragulas callbacks to fire before manipulating DOM add `drake.start(this)` and after manipulation `drake.end()`:

```
drake = dragula([left1, right1]);
drake.on('drop', function(el, target, source, sibling){
console.log(el);
console.log(target);
console.log(source);
console.log(sibling);
});
var leftList = document.querySelector('#left1');
var rightList = document.querySelector('#right1');
var list = document.querySelectorAll('#right1 li, #left1 li');
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  list[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
            drake.start(this);
        if (this.parentNode.id == 'right1') {
        leftList.appendChild(this);
      } else {
        rightList.appendChild(this);
      }
      drake.end();
  });
}
```

Comment: That's terrific! works great. Maybe you would know how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35676922/how-to-replicate-sortable-serialize-but-with-dragula-js trying to get it to work so I can ditch jQuery UI. Let me if you have a chance.